# Store Variable Across Scripts

Tags: python, arrays, variables

I have a helper function that is referenced by multiple scripts. The idea I had is that many scripts can use the helper function to essentially append to a list, and then at some point any one of those scripts could access elements from the list.

Some scripts use traditional 'import ' statements, while others use 'importlib.import_module()' - and the combination of the two seems to cause an issue.

The issue I'm having is that the helper function only stores values that are written to it by the current script.

For example, if I have:

```
Project/
|-- helpers/
|   |--store_value.py
|-- framework/
|   |runner/
|   |   |-- runner.py
|   |validator/
|   |   |-- validator.py
```

And the following in store_value.py:

```
ALL_MSGS = []

def print_message(msg, display_messages=True):
    """
    :param msg: [str] - String to be printed
    :return: None - Work In Progress
    """
    global ALL_MSGS
    ALL_MSGS.append(msg)
    if display_messages:
        print(msg)


def return_all_msgs():
    return ALL_MSGS
```

In Runner.py I have:

```
import store_value, validator
...
store_value.print_message("Calling Validator")
validator.validate()
print(store_value.return_all_msgs())
...
```

And validator.py:

```
importlib.import_module("store_value")
...
store_value.print_message("Running Validator")
...
```

Then I would expect the output to be:

```
["Calling Validator", "Running Validator"]
```

but right now I'm getting:

```
[]
```

Comment: How are you running your scripts?

Answer (score 0):

I put "runner.py", "validator.py" and "store_value.py" all in the same folder and it worked fine. "store_value.py" is the same as yours, and the others are:

runner.py:

```
import store_value, validator

store_value.print_message("Calling Validator")
validator.validate()
print(store_value.return_all_msgs())
```

validator.py:

```
import store_value

def validate():
    store_value.print_message("Running Validator")
```

---

The output:

```
Calling Validator
Running Validator
['Calling Validator', 'Running Validator']
```

Comment: You are correct - this worked for me as well. I found that the issue is occuring when runner.py uses:
    import store_value, validator

But validator.py uses:
    importlib.import_module("store_value")

Comment: Did it solve your issue? If yes please accept the answer, if not please edit your question to provide additional details.